# How to convert the given set of equations into a symmetric form

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

How do I convert the equations
$$\left\{\begin{array}{} 3a +2b+ c & = & 0\\ a+4b+4c & = & 0 \end{array}\right.$$
to the form
$$\frac{a}{4}=\frac{b}{-11}=\frac{c}{10}=k.$$
Thank you

Comment: http://www.themathpage.com/alg/simultaneous-equations.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to relate $\frac a4$ to $b$ and $c$, separately.

First, multiplying the first equation by $2$ gives

$2\times (3a+2b+c)=2\times0 \Leftrightarrow 6a+4b+2c=0$.

Subtracting the second equation from this result gives

$5a-2c=0$

$5a=2c$

$a=\frac{2}{5}c$

$\frac{a}{4}=\frac{c}{10}$.

Similarly, to relate $\frac{a}{4}$ to $b$, you can start by multiplying the second equation by $3$, then subtracting it from the first equation to get

$(3a+2b+c)-(3a+12b+12c)=0$

$-10b-11c=0$

$-11c=10b$

$c=\frac{10b}{-11}$.

Dividing everything by $10$ gives

$\frac{c}{10}=\frac{10b}{-110}=\frac{b}{-11}$.

But we know, $\frac{a}{4}=\frac{c}{10}$, so $\frac{a}{4}=\frac{-b}{11}$.

This simplifies to

$\frac{a}{4}=\frac{b}{-11}=\frac{c}{10}$,

as required.

You can google "linear simultaneous equations" for more details on how to solve this kind of questions.

Comment: $4\times2=8 \ne 6$

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for quick response. A small mistake in multiplication, though not a problem. I'll look up "linear simultaneous equations. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I went a bit too fast!  It has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $a%$ and $b$ in terms of $c$

Then

$$3a+2b=-c$$
$$a+4b = -4c$$

Multiplying the first by $-2$ and adding,

$$-5a = -2c \implies \frac{a}{2}=\frac{c}{5}$$

and $$-10b = 11c \implies \frac{b}{-11} = \frac{c}{10} $$

$$\implies \frac{a}{4}=\frac{b}{-11}=\frac{c}{10}$$

Comment: Thank you. But i already gave correct answer above, so in a dilemma here

Answer (score 0):

Each individual equation in this system describes a plane and the system describes the line which is their intersection. This line is orthogonal to the normals of both planes, so we can find its direction by computing the cross product $$(3,2,1)\times(1,4,4)=(4,-11,10),$$ i.e., the line consists of all points $(a,b,c)=k\,(4,-11,10)=(4k,-11k,10k)$. The symmetric form is obtained by isolating $k$: $$\frac a4=\frac b{-11}=\frac c{10}=k.$$

Comment: Thank you for insight. I understand now the meaning of this system of equation. Why is that the line has to be orthogonal to both planes, can the lines from two planes not intersect each other making an angle with the plane? And i would be glad to know the reason behind taking cross product to find the direction, is is because the line is orthogonal to both the planes?

Comment: @AgentRock The line isn’t orthogonal to the planes themselves. It of course can’t be orthogonal to either one, since it lies within them both. It is, on the other hand, orthogonal to the planes’ *normals*, which you can obtain from their equations. In $\mathbb R^3$ you can then take advantage of the cross product to produce a vector that’s orthogonal to the two normals; in higher-dimensional spaces you’d have to use some other method.

Comment: Sorry if I'm appearing too noob. But how can the line lie in both the planes? Is it because this line passes through both the planes, as they have simultaneous equations. I'm finding it very hard to visualize. I know normal can be found out by taking its gradient.

Comment: @AgentRock The intersection of two sets consists by definition of those elements that they have in common—that are in both of the sets. The two equations specify a set of points that satisfy *both* equations, i.e., that are common to both solution sets. Each equation describes a plane, and the intersection of two planes (if it exists) is a line.

Comment: Wow. That clears it up. Thank you so much.

Comment: After re reading and look up, i finally understood. These equations of plane, on intersection forms not a point but a line. And normal vectors to these planes are orthogonal to line. So naturally by finding the cross product between these two normal vectors would produce a vector that is in the direction of the line of intersection. Thank you so much for your thorough explanation on the real thing. I would have given it best answer, but i already gave. But I'm grateful to you, sir.